# unresolved import `crate::sys` on rust project building

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo, solana

I am working on the Solana contract with rust language.

When I execute `cargo build`, it returns ok result.

But when I execute `cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release`, it returns below the error console.

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys`
 --> /home/ubuntu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.2/src/sockaddr.rs:5:12
  |
5 | use crate::sys::{
  |            ^^^
  |            |
  |            unresolved import
  |            help: a similar path exists: `crate::socket::io::sys`

error[E0432]: unresolved imports `crate::sys`, `crate::sys`
  --> /home/ubuntu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.2/src/socket.rs:21:12
   |
21 | use crate::sys::{self, c_int, getsockopt, setsockopt, Bool};
   |            ^^^   ^^^^ no `sys` in the root
   |            |
   |            unresolved import
   |            help: a similar path exists: `crate::socket::io::sys`
```

...

Please let me know if you faced this kinda issue before.

Comment: It looks like `socket2` only supports `unix`- or `windows`-based platforms: [source](https://docs.rs/socket2/0.4.2/src/socket2/lib.rs.html#122-127)

Comment: @kmdreko, Please let me know the way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On-chain programs are limited in what resources they can access.  For example, you can't access the internet or filesystem.  Your program seems to be relying on some of these forbidden packages.

Here's more info from the documentation about using `rand`, which is also not allowed: https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust#depending-on-rand